# Are there any known exploits against bluetooth mice or keyboards?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

Most wireless mice are not bluetooth.  There are known exploits that take over wireless mice and use them as a keyboard.

Are there known exploits that can remotely inject malware directly over bluetooth RF, read what is being typed or type on the keyboard to download a malicious script?

How would one possibly audit for this since it would require constant intrusion prevention scanning of Radio Frequencies?

Is there proof that BlueTooth is safe?

Comment: BT is encrypted, right?

Comment: BlueTooth is not  usually encrypted as there four security modes for BT.  Like WiFi, there is an open pairing mode.  Only the highest mode seems all that secure, but no one seems to use that.

Comment: Since all bluetoorh devices use USB for charging, it has aggravated me that there is not an automatic exchange of keys over the usb cable to the PC or SmartPhone.

Comment: Wouldn't that require ALL bluetooth devices to properly implement the USB protocol and connect GPIO pins to the microcontroller in order to negotiate a key? Or are you suggesting a 5th encryption method?

 I can imagine this working though... sounds like a really cool idea. Maybe you should design it!

Comment: USB even when implemented correctly cannot prevent root kit install, but I would still  rather risk that to have out-of-band  automated exchange of big keys.

Comment: Most versions of BT _are_ encrypted by default, though often without authentication.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to heavily depend on your version of Bluetooth supported.

Here's the latest [NIST paper](https://www.nist.gov/publications/guide-bluetooth-security-1) with the state of Bluetooth security and recommendations organizations can take to remediate their risk.

That's a good place to start.

Page #37 of the report lists all the Bluetooth vulnerabilities known at time of publication, sorted by the version the vulnerability was discovered in.